# what is Thread Dump data in java .how to store it ,is it helpful in javaoutofmemory

Tags: java

what is Thread Dump data? .How to store it or any file is generated like a logger,is  it  helpful in javaoutofmemory. If issue come instantly on production then may i track the issue reason by reading the Thread Dump data?Please suggest...

Answer (score 1):

Thread dump of a java processes at any point of time is snapshot of what all the threads are doing in that jvm at that time.

you can use utilities like [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) to get threaddump

Not sure if you can find the actual cause of OOM from the thread dump as it will usually tell you what thread is doing what (more useful for resolving deadlock kind  of issues), but it may still help considering what process is waiting.

A thread dump doesnt show how much memory a java process is consuming, rather a heap dump will help you more. From it you can find what objects are consuming major chunk of memory.

To generate a memory dump you can use [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html)

You can also connect your java process to a profiler like [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/)

with this you can analyze the cpu and memory usage of your java process at realtime.
You can also generate thread dump and heap dump using it.

*All these three tools come with jdk, you don't need to install anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean Thread Dump is javacore. Javacore is snapshot of the running java process. It includes JVM command line, environments and loaded libraries. It provides a snaphot of all the running threads, their stacktraces and the monitors(locks) held by threads. Also Garbage Collection history and memory information.

If you need the solve OutOfMemory(OOM) problem you need to analyze heapdump file which shows the created objects using java heap memory. After found the object caused the OOM You can match which thread can generate that object.

You can also read this article http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/jvm-how-to-analyze-thread-dump.html.

Comment: In IBM JRE world thread dump is javacore

Comment: ah, it indeed [seems so](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r2mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wps.620.doc/doc/rtroub_capture_java_core.html). You'll learn something new every day.